# Firefox 119 won't trust a self signed Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate

Tags: kubernetes, firefox, kubectl

I'm doing Kubectl / Kubernetes development on a local machine and while trying to reach the web page get these errors from browser:

```
Did Not Connect: Potential Security Issue giving
Error code: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
```

The Kubernetes certificate is there:

```
curl -skv https://ticketing.dev
*   Trying 192.168.49.2:443...
...
* Server certificate:
*  subject: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  start date: Nov  5 19:13:41 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Nov  4 19:13:41 2024 GMT
*  issuer: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
```

Added these settings to the browser to no effect either:

```
security.certerrors.permanentOverride = false
security.enterprise_roots.enabled = true
```

How do I get the page to display? Did add the page location to the trusted certs list in the browser settings.